# How to use articles with scientific words, such as mass, force, impulse, field and others?

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

How are articles used with scientific quantities, such as mass, force, impulse, field and others?

Comment: To paraphrase RegDwigнt: why do you think articles are to be used different with scientific words than with other words? Maybe you would get more response - and more useful - if you provided some more details, maybe some example sentences with specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same as with any other word.

Indeed, *scientific* means a word is particularly associated with science, or that it has a sense that is. In terms of syntax and grammar they are the same as any other word.

So, in taking just *mass* as an example:

In talking about it as a concept, we use no article:

> Mass is a property of a physical body that determines its resistance to being accelerated by a force.

Because concepts are uncountable, so in that uncountable sense we use no article.

Otherwise we choose between *the* or *a* depending on whether we are specific or general:

> The earth has a mass of 5.97219 × 10<sup>24</sup> kg.
>
> The mass of the earth is 5.97219 × 10<sup>24</sup> kg.

Comment: Thank u! I think i'll understand someday how to use the articles absolutely right.

Comment: They mostly relate to number (with uncountable senses having no number) and specificity (*the* is specific, *a* and *some* are general). Proper nouns are the tricky case, especially since some lower-case proper nouns fool native speakers (they use them correctly, but couldn't explain why). One thing that confuses some is that books will often talk of words as countable or uncountable, when really it's senses that are.